# Remote performance monitoring Windows 8.1 machines

Tags: windows-8.1, remote, performance-monitor

I want to be able to monitor the performance of some remote machines from my local machine.

Here is my setup so far:

- local machine: Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit;
- remote machines: Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit;
- all machines in the default `WORKGROUP` workgroup - no HomeGroup, no domain;
- all machines in the same private network ("private" as in Windows 8.1's concept of "public"/"private" network)
- for convenience, same username and password on all remote and local machines - let's call the user "bob";
- "bob" belongs to these groups on *all remote and local machines*:

  - Administrators
  - Event Log Readers
  - Performance Log Users
  - Performance Monitor Users
- These services are enabled and running on *all remote and local machines*:

  - Performance Counter DLL Host
  - Performance Logs & Alerts
  - Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
  - Remote Registry
- Allowed apps and features in Windows Firewall on the *remote and local machines*:

  - Performance Logs and Alerts

So far, The only thing that I can do from my local machine is to connect to a remote computer and start a Data Collector Set:

[image: You can see the button to start the data collector set is enabled.]

But then I cannot stop it:

[image: The "stop" button is not enabled after I start the data collector set.]

And if I disconnect and reconnect, **all** data collector sets completely disappear:

[image: Where have all the collector sets gone? Gone to graveyards, everyone. When will they ever learn?]

Also, at no point can I get a report of the remote data collector set.

So I figure that maybe instead of using a *remote* data collector set, maybe I should use a *local* data collector set, but with *remote performance counters*, so I try to browse to the remote computer to add performance counters:

[image]

But then it asks me for username and password:

[image: Why doesn't this work the same way as file sharing? It's the same username and password as the local machine. Don't ask me again!]

After I supply the username and password and click "OK", I have to wait a whole minute, and then it comes back with this useless message:

[image]

It's really frustrating. Windows clearly could find the remote computer when I started the remote data collector set. So why can't it find the same remote computer when I want to access its performance counters? The message tells me nothing about what's missing. I also couldn't find any useful information on MSDN/TechNet.

Comment: You didn't find [Setting a remote perfmon in a Windows client or Windows Server.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2015/05/16/setting-a-remote-perfmon-in-a-windows-client-or-windows-server.aspx)?

Comment: [Using Performance Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc749115.aspx) - "Membership in the target computer's Performance Log Users group, or equivalent, is the minimum required to complete this procedure."

Answer (score 2):

#### But then I cannot stop it

To stop the monitoring process, type the following command, and then press enter:

```
monitor \\remotecomputer stop
```

---

#### How to Monitor Performance of a Remote Computer Without Logging on to It

> To log data and generate alerts on a remote computer without having to
>   log on to it, follow these steps:
>
> NOTE: In the following steps, replace  with the name
>   of the computer that you want to monitor.
>
> 1. Install the Windows NT 4.0 Resource Kit on the remote computer.
> 2. At the local computer, use Windows NT Performance Monitor (Perfmon.exe) to create a workspace file:
>
>    - Start Performance Monitor, and then click Log on the View menu.
>    - Add the relevant counters, specifying all objects you want to log and the alerts you want to generate.
>    - On the Options menu, click Log.
>    - In the File Name box, specify a name for the log file using the .log extension.
>    - Click one of the logging interval options, and then click Save to save the logging options.
>    - On the File menu, click Save Workspace.
>    - In the File Name box, type a workspace file name using the .pmw extension, and then click Save.
>    - Quit Performance Monitor.
> 3. Copy both the workspace file you just created and the Datalog.exe file included with the Windows NT 4.0 Resource Kit to the
>      `%SystemRoot%\System32` folder on the remote computer.
> 4. At the local computer, set up the Data Logging service for the remote computer:
>
>    - At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press enter:
>
>      `monitor \\remotecomputer setup`
>
>      NOTE: This command registers the service with Windows NT Server 4.0. You need to run the command only once for each computer
>        you want to monitor. If you receive the following error message
>
>      `Failed to create Service`
>
>      it means that you have already run the command once.
>    - To use the workspace file for logging, type the following command, and then press enter:
>
>      `monitor \\remotecomputer filename`
>
>      where filename is the name of the workspace file you copied to the remote computer.
> 5. To start the monitoring process, type the following command, and then press enter:
>
>    `monitor \\remotecomputer start`
> 6. To stop the monitoring process, type the following command, and then press enter:
>
>    `monitor \\remotecomputer stop`
>
>    - After you stop the monitoring process, you can view the log file in Performance Monitor. For instructions about how to do this, see Help
>        in Performance Monitor.
>    - Also, you can use the Schedule service and the AT command to schedule monitoring to occur at a set time. For example, if a server
>        slows down noticeably between 2:40 A.M. and 2:50 A.M. every weeknight,
>        you can log the data for that period without being physically present
>        by typing the following AT commands:
>
>      `at \\remotecomputer 2:30 /every:m,t,w,th,f monitor start`
>
>      `at \\remotecomputer 3:00 /every:m,t,w,th,f monitor stop`
>    - If you want to be reminded about the log, type the following command, and then press enter:
>
>      `at \\remotecomputer 3:00 /every:f net send yourusername 'The Monitor is stopped. The log contains data for this week!'`

Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246758

Answer (score -1):

Another thing to consider is 
Click Properties (icon on the top) --> General Tab --> Change “Run as “to the windows account that has permissions in remote machine 
That worked for me, after adding the user account to Performance Log user groups.